# Django - Check an integer must to start with 9 and length is 10 with regex

Tags: regex, django

Where is my mistake?

```
mobile = forms.IntegerField(
    label='Mobile',
    widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'required': 'required'
    }),
    error_messages={
        'invalid': 'Required',
    }
)

def clean_mobile(self):
    mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']

    if not re.match('^((?!([0-8]))[0-9]{9})$', str(mobile)):
        self.add_error('mobile', 'Wrong number')

    return mobile
```

Always returns `False`!

Comment: What is your input? and the length is `9` obviously. Try `^9[0-9]{9}$`

Comment: @revo Question has been updated.

Comment: @revo It worked. tnx. May submit as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex you are looking for a digit which is not in range `[0-8]` at beginning of input string that literally means `9`. Negative lookahead asserts then gives back cursor at position before first character. You then look for 9 digits and end of string which immediately fails on 10 digit numbers.

Try this:

```
^9\d{9}$
```

Comment: With first 9 length being 10. It works. Thanks dude.